# what .NET class to proxy HTTP requests through? (and keep track of bandwidth used)

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, httpwebrequest, proxy-server

What .NET class/methods could I use to write a simple HTTP(s) proxy that would run on my PC that would:

- Proxy all HTTP(S) requests through it
- Let me get bandwidth used per proxy'ed request (e.g. content length)
- Let me get requesting application or process name per proxied request
- Ability to proxy/stream the requests on through to my normal proxy server (server name, port, username, password)

Comment: FWIW I believe this a reverse-proxy you are looking for. If you don't plan to distribute the requests to multiple interior servers I don't see why you couldn't achieve all of this with a simple HTTP module.

Comment: hey Chris - what do you mean?  Is there something you have in mind I can look at?  Like pound or squid in reverse proxy mode?

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this on the client side, right?

I think that `WebRequest` is probably what you are looking for.  As far as how to hook it in to the OS... that's a different question.

Comment: I think some clarification could be added to the question, from what I took it the OP meant was to track the bandwidth consumed from actions that clients invoke from his server.

Comment: That's correct Chris - but everything is on the one pc, ie both the clients that use Internet bandwidth that I want tot track, and the target location for the software I want to build to track it

Comment: Re webrequest, this might be part of it I guess, however the software needs to listen to new requests and then chain/pass them on, ie proxy, as well